# Embed xna game in a webpage

Tags: browser, xna, html

Is there a way to run an xna game from a web page without installing anything? Something similiar to java, silverlight or very close to a wpf browser applications (XBAP).

Scenario:

> Go on webpage, Get asked to install
>   the game. Game installs, game screen
>   shows up in webpage. Can full screen,
>   etc.

The game is a full blown xna framework game, using 3d, has access to the system calls such as directx and other low level networking api. This is probably more of having javascript working with windows system if anything.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[SilverSprite](http://www.codeplex.com/silversprite) seems to do what you want. I have never used it but see [XNA 2D games come to the browser via Silverlight](http://arstechnica.com/microsoft/news/2009/03/xna-2d-games-come-to-the-browser-via-silverlight.ars).

> Essentially it allows XNA game
>   developers to run their games in
>   Silverlight 2, though there is a
>   limitation: the games that can be
>   converted may only have
>   SpriteBatch-based graphics, meaning no
>   3D games.

Comment: The article is referring to SilverSprite.

Comment: Its a complete xna game, not silverlight. Uses directx 3d api, etc.

Comment: You should read the article. SilverSprite is a framework that mirrors the XNA framework. Using SilverSprite you can create a SilverLight browser game based on your already created XNA game.

Comment: But since you are using 3D it doesn't matter as SilverSprite only has support for SpriteBatch drawing.

Answer (score 2):

If your game needs access at the level you describe then it can't really run from within the browser. It will need to be properly installed on the users machine.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [ClickOnce](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ClickOnce) installer to launch your came FROM a web page, but not run it IN a webpage.

Answer (score 0):

The Unity game engine (and designer) is pretty darned fabulous for doing exactly what you describe. You can do all the logic in C# if desired.