# How to make an executable for a website on xna

Tags: c#, web-applications, xna, cross-browser

I just made a game using xna and I was thinking of making a website to host all my games to come and I was wondering how I could do that. Any suggestions of how I could make my xna game run off a website?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528468/embed-xna-game-in-a-webpage

Answer (score 2):

If you want games that run on a HTML page use Flash or JavaScript with HTML5 Canvas.

XNA games are native applications (managed code...) and will not run in a browser. You can create web site with links to install your game...

Answer (score 0):

You can port `SpriteBatch`-based (ie: 2D) XNA games to Silverlight using [ExEn](http://andrewrussell.net/exen/). (Note: ExEn is my product, currently in active development.)

You could also use [SilverSprite](http://silversprite.codeplex.com/), although it's kind of old.

And Silverlight 5 has built-in support for some of the XNA APIs (particularly for sound and 3D graphics).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a site that ports [XNA to HTML5](http://hildr.luminance.org/Platformer/Platformer.html).  I believe that the XNA version needs to be 3.1 in order for it to work.  Also, I don't think that it will do 3D.